# MouseOver on asp.net webform

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a asp.net webform with labels and textboxes and would like to include help image next to label so that when i mouseover on the image it should bring the help description from the table in the database. Can someone help me how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**pls see this link :**

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$(".myDiv").live('keyup focus focusout change click mouseenter mouseover',function(){
         // Your command
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are allot of Jquery tooltip plugins, from the built in one to fancy looking stuff. Have you looked at any of these?

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/